# how to build a any.do like deletion gesture?

Tags: android, view, gesture

I am new to android, I want to develop some UI like any.do, I have two questions:

1. How to build a any.do like deletion gesture? When you finger sweep cross the item, it will add a line over the item?
2. What should the layout file look like, when you have titleA + some list items and TitleB+some list items on the same view?

Comment: I would say probably create a listview first, make sure that works, and then ask questions about how to add gesture events to the items and add headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess you mean that gray line that is "crossing" the task. It fairly simple actually, just create a a line shape, using a drawable xml, and animate it's size from 0 to the full width of the task.
2. Didn't quite understand the layout you are referring to? Is it the gray line layout? The list item layout?